# CSS3 - Embedded font disappears in chrome when rotated?

Tags: css, fonts, rotation, embedded-fonts

I've been playing with CSS3 transforms- rotations- and embedded fonts.

Some fonts [completely disappear](http://jsfiddle.net/DFmtJ/) in Chrome when I apply a rotation.

- Does anyone know why chrome blows this up?
- What makes a font susceptible to this behavior?

**Screenshot**

So maybe y'all don't think I'm crazy- The text only shows up (kind of) after I try selecting it.

[image: FONTS! Y U NO SHOW UP?]

Comment: Works for me (chrome v. 15.0.874.5 dev-m)

Comment: Works for me (macbook and chrome 13.0.782.220)

Comment: I'm on Chrome 13.0.782.220, Windows

Answer (score 0):

You weren't including the font correctly, try it like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/DFmtJ/1/

(tested on windows XP, Chrome 11.0.696.68 and 13.0.782.220)

------Edit--------

Cried wolf, the font that was being loaded was another one :/, though it is working for me on Chrome as in your first demo.

Comment: Thanks for the effort.  It seems to be something specific about that font- I don't have any expertise in this area so I'm at a total loss for theories.  Beautiful font though :(